# Json file exists but server gives http 404 status

Tags: jquery, json, tomcat

The task given is on page load, display json data from file.
            I'm trying to access data  in .json file using jquery,

```
      I notice there is file studentinfo.json listed under sources-JsonTrial folder.

      No clue and this has eaten my full day at work..!! please some one help. 

        here is my json file: studentinfo.json  

     {"studentsjson":[
      { "name":"Henry  Lee", "course":"reading", "year":"2000", "grade":"3"},
      { "name":"John Flex", "course":"writing", "year":"2001", "grade":"4"},
      { "name":"Adam Debby", "course":"math", "year":"1999", "grade":"5"},
      { "name":"Louis Peter", "course":"Science", "year":"2000", "grade":"6"}
     ]
   }
```

Comment: when I saw few tutorial online, and found the  work folder kept in web server.
        I kept the folder JsonTrial (which has all above files) in Tomcat webapps folder.
          started server and able to access html page
          could see alert(1) , $("p").html("hello paragraph"); successfully.

Comment: here is my js file: jsonread.js

        $(window).load(function(){
         alert(1);
            $("p").html("hello paragraph");
               $.getJSON("studentinfo.json",function(data){
           $.each(data.studentsjson, function(){
                 $("ul").append("<li>Name:"+this['name']+"</li>");
            });//end of each callback
             });//end of getjson callback
                    });
    
                  });// end of load fun

Comment: and here is my html file: readingJson.html
    
             <!DOCTYPE html>
             <html><head>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="jsonread.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="studentinfo.json"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1 id="heading h1" >Hello H1  </h1>
              <p></p>
                <ul></ul>
              </body>
                </html>

Comment: I kept jquery.js  and all files exists in single folder.      
                      
           I don't know why? but when i inspect the element (html page), I see there exists
           Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found):